# How to show model data in django template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I am working on project and i have a problem with it.The problem is that django is not showing model data in template and i an unable to solve problem.
Here is the **models.py**

```
 from django.db import models
 from django.contrib.auth.models 
 import User
 from django.utils.timezone 
 import now

class videopost(models.Model):

 sno=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)  slug=models.CharField(max_length=130)
title=models.CharField(max_length=255)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='staticfiles/images/')
content=models.TextField()
timeStamp=models.DateTimeField(blank=True)


   def__str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Here is **views.py**

```
def videoposts(request,slug):

    post=videopost.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()
    context={'post':post}

    return render(request,'videos/videopost.html',context)
```

And here is **template**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load embed_video_tags %}
{% block title %}How to run python in mobile?{% endblock title %}
{% block basecss%}"{% static '/css/home.css' %}" {% endblock basecss %}
{% block extracss %}"{% static '/css/videos.css' %}" {% endblock extracss %}


{% block classvideos%} current {% endblock classvideos %}
{% block body %}
            
{{post.content}}            
{{post.title}}
{% endblock body %}
```

Comment: what is the error that you get?

Comment: I am not getting any error.

Comment: model data is not showing in template when i run server

Comment: what URL are you trying to visit? Have you created a model instance with the slug value that you are trying to query for?

Answer (score 1):

Check weather your post object is `None`. Try to print it.

Comment: I have solved the problem by editing slug value in database

Comment: Thangs for helping me

Answer (score 0):

As i see in your code u putting your slug as kwarg, and actually don't close the bracket:

```
sno=models.AutoField(primary_key=True   slug=models.CharField(max_length=130)
```

If it's not copying error do like this maybe:

```
sno=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
slug=models.SlugField(max_length=130)
```

Comment: If u doing all right and passing valid slug in url try to debug line post=videopost.objects.filter(slug=slug).first() to be sure that u are getting object from database

Comment: or just write print(post) after that line

Comment: I don't understand what's the problem

Comment: It means it can't get object from database with that slug. If you get it it will fix your problem. Try to write post=videopost.objects.get(slug=slug) instead of post=videopost.objects.filter(slug=slug).first() and be sure you are passing valid item slug in url